# should login validations be handled in stored procedure or Data Access Layer?

Tags: database-design, stored-procedures, architecture, data-access-layer

hi i'm building a small web-app using AngularJs and c# wcf restful services..and there is a login module which has a stored procedure with minimal code which just validates whether the  username/password provided is correct and here is the code

```
 alter procedure sp_loginTable
(
@username varchar(50),
@password varchar(25),
@output bit out
)
as

declare @queryedUsername varchar(50)
declare @queryedPassword varchar(25)
select @queryedUsername =username,@queryedPassword=password from userLoginTable where username='surya'
if ((@queryedUsername=@username) and (@queryedPassword=@password))
SET @output=1
ELSE
 SET @output=0
GO
```

and there is a password "123456aA" which is stored in the table..if i give "123456aa" as input the code always returns 1..and i have searched many stack overflow questions where people suggested various solutions on string comparions but the code is very large..

string comparisions are easy to implement in C# if we write

```
string nameone = "123456aA";
string nametwo = "123456aa";
Console.WriteLine(nameone.Equals(nametwo));//returns false
```

there is an equal method which does proper string comparion..

so is it best to move the login validation to dataAccessLayer or should i perform the validation in a stored procedure?..i prefer not to write large chunk of code in stored procedure simply for this validation as c# has a built in function which handles string comparision smoothly..

give ur valuable inputs..

Thanks

Comment: Did you... store the password as it is, in the database? Without hashing?

Comment: yes will do all that stuff..it is in a starting phase and this is just a temporary table and a temporary stored procedure thats it :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many debates about where to store the business logic: in the database or in de business layer or another layer.

I assume you are not talking about validating who can access the database (like your process), I assume you are talking about validating the users who have access to your application (and indirectly the database).

In that case this is my opinion:

- The responsibility of the database is to store data and make it available on request very fast. Making data available could be done by sql, but stored procedures can help. So the database should worry about managing data.
- The responsibility of the DataAccessLayer is to make the assess to the database easier from your code. The client code simply calls a single function and that funcion will create a connection to the database, create a command, etc. etc. So a DataAccessLayer should only worry about (technical) connectivity.
- Another component, not in your question, is the BusinessLayer or BusinessLogicLayer. His responsibility is to do all functional stuff. Like calculations, checking business rules, validation, etc. etc. The business logic is placed between your User Interface and the DataAccessLayer.

Since username/password validation is part of your application functionality, it belongs inside your BusinessLogic.

Comment: thx Martin Mulder for a quick post.. :).. oh so this login proc should only care about fetching records and the validations should be in BusinessLoginLayer..hmm i got you..thnks man..